# DraftJS Component Takes too much Space Inside Flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, react-draft-wysiwyg

I'm embedding [React Draft Wysiwyg](https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/) component within a flexbox. The flexbox should consist of this component alongside a circle div.

For some reason, the circle div gets squished and is not circular, but instead is narrower than it should be.

I can reduce this 'squishiness' by passing the `wrapperClassName` prop and adding `w-fit` (which is the Tailwind equivalent of `width: fit-content;` in pure CSS), however, the circle is still squished on narrower screens.

**Image:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
<div className='flex gap-x-2 items-center w-full min-w-[480px] h-full py-3 px-2 bg-gray-50 rounded'>

    {/* Rich text editor component */}
    <Editor 
        wrapperClassName='w-fit'
    />
    
    {/* Circle */}
    <div className={'group w-9 h-9 rounded-full'} />
    
</div>
```

How can I get the `Editor` component to take all remaining width without taking away the space that the circle div needs to remain a proportional circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give the Editor `w-full` and give the circle a `p-5` instead of `w-9`

Is this what you meant: https://play.tailwindcss.com/cPxzlro2re